# api to get uid from profile URL on facebook

Tags: facebook

Is there a way (using API) to get users *uid* from the *profile URL* in facebook?

Comment: I think you may be out of luck on this one

Comment: This question needs to be reviewed again as username queries were deprecated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can call the graph directly as such:
https://graph.facebook.com/username where username is the username you want to lookup.

Comment: Still working, but now it needs an access token to read the resource. See more at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/using-graph-api/?locale=en_US.

Comment: This has been depreciated.

Answer (score 5):

The REST api has been deprecated.

The proper way to do this is to pass the profile name to the graph api

see: [Facebook ID from URL](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/4789120/facebook-id-from-url)

Answer (score -2):

Use [Users.getInfo](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.getInfo), which returns an array of user info, such as `first_name`, `last_name`, and **`uid`**. Use this call to get user data that you intend to display to other users (of your application, for example). If you need some basic information about a user for analytics purposes, call [users.getStandardInfo](http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Users.getStandardInfo) instead.

Answer (score -2):

As of today(28th July 2015), I found a different way to find Facebook user's numeric id from profile url (or username).

As you all will be knowing the profile url syntax is *https://www.facebook.com/[username]*

So just browse to profile url, right click to view source and search for string **"uid":**. You will get numeric id next to it.

Comment: Waste Solution! Needed a more generic code wise solution