# Graph API - how to get ID of user by username

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Facebook API endpoint

```
 https://graph.facebok.com/{username}
```

stopped work in recent two weeks. Temporarily  pages like www.findmyfacebookid.com didn't return proper results, but now they works fine.

How can I grab userId from Graph API now?

I know about stragne workaround with data-hovercard parameter. Manner described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26062011/facebook-graph-api-2-1-get-userid-from-username). However, I find it hard to believe that they use such a odd solution especially I know tools which probably use another way and have not outages. Does anybody know more efficient way to get that data? Your help appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to use the username anymore, only the App Scoped User ID you get after authorizing a User. I assume those tools switched to parsing the Facebook User profile, which is not allowed according to the [scraping terms](https://www.facebook.com/apps/site_scraping_tos_terms.php).